# Как передать массив Integer в хранимую процедуру в БД Oracle?

Tags: java, spring, oracle

Есть процедура в БД

```
create or replace procedure p_role_obj_access_add
( pnIdRole            number,
  pttnIdObj           tt_number,
  pttnIdObjPermission tt_number,
  pvErr           out varchar2
  ) is
```

Тип tt_number представлен как :

```
create or replace type tt_number as table of number
```

Есть метод:

```
public String insert(String sql, Integer role_id, Integer [] obj_id, Integer [] permission_id) throws Exception {...}
```

Параметры которого следующие:

```
String sql = "p_role_obj_access_add"; //Имя процедуры
Integer role_id = 2;
Integer [] obj_id//массив Integer
Integer [] permission_id//То же самое
```

Внутри этого метода пишу вот так

```
public String insert(String sql, Integer role_id, Integer [] obj_id, Integer [] permission_id) throws Exception {
   SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName(sql);
  
          simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(
                  new SqlParameter(
                          "pnIdRole",
                          OracleTypes.NUMBER),
                  new SqlParameter(
                          "pttnIdObj",
                          OracleTypes.ARRAY),
                  new SqlParameter(
                          "pttnIdObjPermission",
                          OracleTypes.ARRAY),
                  new SqlInOutParameter(
                          "pvErr",
                          OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
  
          MapSqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource();
          in.addValue("pnIdRole", role_id);
          in.addValue("pttnIdObj", obj_id);
          in.addValue("pttnIdObjPermission", permission_id);
          in.addValue("pvErr", null);
  
          Map<String, Object> resultMap = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
  
          return "success"; //Должен возвращать результат из resultMap
  
      }
```

Получаю ошибку

```
13:33:41.547 [http-bio-8085-exec-2] INFO  o.s.j.s.SQLErrorCodesFactory#126 SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call P_ROLE_OBJ_ACCESS_ADD(?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17059]; Сбой преобразования во внутреннее представление: [Ljava.lang.Integer;@b13ef4; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Сбой преобразования во внутреннее представление: [Ljava.lang.Integer;@b13ef4
```

Сбой преобразования во внутреннее представление?
Что это значит и что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, сделал вот так. Оно заработало. Теперь только так и работаю.

```
public String insertRoleDetails(Integer role_id, Integer[] idsObj, Integer[] idsPermission, Integer system_user_id) {

        String retval = null;
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
            ArrayDescriptor tt_number = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("TT_NUMBER", conn);
            CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call p_role_obj_access_add(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }");
            ARRAY obj_id_array = new ARRAY(tt_number, conn, idsObj);
            ARRAY permission_id_array = new ARRAY(tt_number, conn, idsPermission);
            stmt.setObject(1, role_id);
            stmt.setObject(2, obj_id_array);
            stmt.setObject(3, permission_id_array);
            stmt.setObject(4, system_user_id);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(6, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            boolean res = stmt.execute();

            map.put("PNERR", ((OracleCallableStatement) stmt).getInt(5));
            map.put("PVERR", ((OracleCallableStatement) stmt).getString(6));

            conn.commit();
            retval = Util.getMsgFromMapAsJSON(map);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info(e.toString());
            logger.info("-------------Exception---------insertRoleDetails-------");
            retval = JSONWorker.getErrorJSONEasyUI("Системная ошибка");
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.info(e.toString());
                logger.info("-------------SQLException---------insertRoleDetails----COULDNT_CLOSE_CONNECTION---");
                return retval;
            }
            return retval;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Оракл не знает в какой тип он должен конвертировать ваш массив.

Наверное вы забыли указать тип как он определён в схеме. Поробуйте заменить:

```
new SqlParameter("pttnIdObj", OracleTypes.ARRAY),
```

на

```
new SqlParameter("pttnIdObj", OracleTypes.ARRAY, "TT_NUMBER")),
```

[Источник](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html#orcl.datatypes.array)

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример вызова функции с входным массивом объектов(из бд).

```
    OracleConnection connectionOracle = null;
    connectionOracle = connect.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
    callableStatement = connect.prepareCall("{? = call pakage.prod_name(?)}");

    Object arrObj[] = new Object[2];
    //в этих дескрипторах нужно передавать типы обьекта, который ты обьявил у себя в бд
    ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("tt_number_TYPE", connectionOracle);
    StructDescriptor structDescriptor =  StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("tt_number_OBJ", connectionOracle);

    arrObj[0] = new STRUCT(getStructDescriptor(connectionOracle), connectionOracle, new Object[]{276891});
    arrObj[1] = new STRUCT(getStructDescriptor(connectionOracle), connectionOracle, new Object[]{276732});
    ARRAY array = new ARRAY(getArrayDescriptor(connectionOracle), connectionOracle, arrObj);

    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
    callableStatement.setArray(2, array);
    callableStatement.executeQuery();
```